# How can I change permission on folder inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, heroku-cli

I was trying to push container on heroku but I get this error when changing permission

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest

ENV PORT=80

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip  \
            php7.4 php7.4-fpm \
            nginx gettext-base sudo

COPY ./webapp /var/www/myapp

WORKDIR /var/www/myapp

COPY default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

USER docker

RUN  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

RUN  chmod -R 755 /var/www

CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I have this error

```
Step 10/12 : RUN  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
 ---> Running in c5952535d0cc
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/html': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/myapp/index.php': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/myapp/.gitignore': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/myapp': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www': Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www' returned a non-zero code: 1
 !    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USER docker

RUN  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

`USER docker` will cause all subsequent `RUN` commands to be run as `docker` user (see [`USER` docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)), however this user does not have permissions to change ownership of `/var/www` during the build, hence your error.

You should run your `chown` command before setting `docker` user, something like:

```
# [ ... ]
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

RUN  chmod -R 755 /var/www

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

USER docker
```

Or even better:

```
# [ ... ]
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www && \
  chmod -R 755 /var/www && \
  useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && \
  adduser docker sudo

USER docker
```

Which would [use less layers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers)